# Python3: Custom Encrypted Headers URLLIB - KrakenAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, urllib, kraken.com

Alright, so I'm a little outside of my league on this one I think.
I'm attempting to facilitate custom HTTP headers what is noted here:

```
    API-Key = API key
    API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

from https://www.kraken.com/help/api

I'm trying to work solely out of urllib if at all possible.

Below is one of many attempts to get it encoded like required:

```
    import os
    import sys
    import time
    import datetime
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.parse
    import json
    import hashlib
    import hmac
    import base64

    APIKey = 'ThisKey'
    secret = 'ThisSecret'

    data = {}

    data['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)

    data['asset'] = 'ZUSD'

    uripath = '/0/private/TradeBalance'

    postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

    encoded = (str(data['nonce']) + postdata).encode()
    message = uripath.encode() + hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest()

    signature = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(secret),
                    message, hashlib.sha512)
    sigdigest = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

    #this is purely for checking how things are coming along.
    print(sigdigest.decode())

    headers = {
    'API-Key': APIKey,
    'API-Sign': sigdigest.decode()
    }
```

The above may be working just fine, where I'm struggling now is appropriately getting it to the site.
This is my most recent attempt:

```
    myBalance = urllib.urlopen('https://api.kraken.com/0/private/TradeBalance', urllib.parse.urlencode({'asset': 'ZUSD'}).encode("utf-8"), headers)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Credit where due btw, part of this code was pulled from: https://github.com/veox/python3-krakenex
But due to it using requests, I wasn't able to get it functioning on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlopen` doesn't support adding headers, so you need to create a `Request` object and pass it to `urlopen`:

```
url = 'https://api.kraken.com/0/private/TradeBalance'
body = urllib.parse.urlencode({'asset': 'ZUSD'}).encode("utf-8")
headers = {
    'API-Key': APIKey,
    'API-Sign': sigdigest.decode()
}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=body, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Thanks friend! Now it's coming back with "{'error': ['EAPI:Invalid key']}", which makes me think somewhere I've encoded everything wrong.